# Checking SubString in ArrayList

Tags: java

I'm looping in for loop to check the substring of the elements:
example: titles-->[Manager, Marketing Manager, Sales, Sales and Marketing Manager]
Expected Result: [ Sales and Marketing Manager]
Since manager is the substring of Marketing Manager I am removing the element manager, then Sales is the Substring of Sales and Marketing Manager so I am removing sales element from the array and also marketing Manager is the substring of Sales and Marketting Manager so removing Marketing Manager From the list so finaly output will be [Sales and Marketing Manager]

```
static String removeSecWords(List<String> titles) {


         for (int j = 0; j < titles.size(); j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < titles.size(); k++) {
                    if (j == k)
                        continue;
                    if (titles.get(j).contains(titles.get(k))) {
                        titles.remove(k);

                    }
                }
            }
    return (titles.toString());
}
```

I am getting error IndexOutOfBounds exception can any tell me how do this.

Comment: I think the nature of the problem is that items are removed from the list while iterating over it using the index. After removing an item the list is shorter, but the loop still tries to examine those indices (which no longer exist, causing the IndexOutOfBounds exception). There are probably better solutions, but iterating over the list in reverse would avoid this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove from `titles`, `j` could become equal to `titles.size();`, so next time you try `titles.get(j)` you get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. To fix your code, you need to think what to do about both `k` and `j`.

When you remove from `titles`, you do *not* want to increment `k` because otherwise an element will get skipped. I've written `k--;` as a quick and lazy fix, but normally I do not recommend changing the index in a traditional `for` loop.

Also, if `j` is after the position you remove at, you need to change the `j` index too, so it still refers to the same element. Try this version:

```
for (int j = 0; j < titles.size(); j++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < titles.size(); k++) {
        if (j != k && titles.get(j).contains(titles.get(k))) {
            titles.remove(k);
            if (j > k)
                j--;
            k--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok... I tried it but I am getting the ouput [Sales, Sales and Marketing Manager].. When we break the loop still one more comparison is pending.

Comment: @Anji This is very confusing, but I think I've fixed it.

Comment: @ Paul Boddington This is excellent .. I think I am getting desired result ... I will test few more scenarios ... Thanks

Comment: @Anji I've improved it again. If you change the `j` index, you do not need to check for `j == titles.size()` any more.

Comment: yes... I also taught in the same line no need to check the titles.size() ... and about to post you regarding this

Answer (score 3):

your code is unsafe: you remove things in the list, and in the same time, you use size(). You have to separate this.

one solution with a separate Set:

```
static String removeSecWords(List<String> titles) {

    // Keep all at begining
    Set<String> to_keep=new HashSet<String>();
    for (int j = 0; j < titles.size(); j++)
        to_keep.add(titles.get(j));

    for (int j = 0; j < titles.size(); j++) {
           for (int k = 0; k < titles.size(); k++) {
               if (j == k)
                   continue;

               if ((to_keep.contains(titles.get(j)) && (to_keep.contains(titles.get(k)))))
                   if (titles.get(j).contains(titles.get(k)))
                        {
                        to_keep.remove(titles.get(k)); 
                        }
           }
       }

    return (to_keep.toString());
```

}